# Faking a lazy out parameter value on a generic interface in FakeItEasy?

Tags: .net, xunit, fakeiteasy

I have a generic C# interface that I'm trying to mock with FakeItEasy for an xUnit test like this:

```
    #region FakeItEasyDebugging
    public interface IFakeTest<T> : IDisposable where T : new()
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Data key</param>
        /// <param name="data">Data from database, null if not found</param>
        /// <returns>Returns True if found</returns>
        bool GetData(string key, out T data);
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class FakeTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestFakeItEasy()
        {
            const string testKey = "some";

            IFakeTest<TestClass> testObj = A.Fake<IFakeTest<TestClass>>();
            A.CallTo(() => testObj.GetData(testKey, out data)).Returns(true).AssignsOutAndRefParameters(new TestClass());

        }
    }

    #endregion
```

But, this doesn't work even though it looks a lot like what the docs would instruct me to do:

https://fakeiteasy.github.io/docs/8.0.0/assigning-out-and-ref-parameters/

The error message I get is CS0103: The name 'data' does not exist in the current context.

I'm not getting any useful suggestions from Visual Studio either.

So, how should I write the CallTo line to actually make it work and get to specify how the mock IFakeTest.GetData method is to behave?

```
    A.CallTo(() => testObj.GetData(testKey, out TestClass data)).Returns(true).AssignsOutAndRefParameters(new TestClass());
```

Yields CS8198.

```
    A.CallTo(() => testObj.GetData(testKey, out TestClass)).Returns(true).AssignsOutAndRefParameters(new TestClass());
```

Yields CS0118.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, the compiler is complaining to you because you haven't defined `data` anywhere. Whether FakeItEasy was being used or not, `GetData(testKey, out data)` won't compile without declaring `data`.

```cs
TestClass data;
A.CallTo(() => testObj.GetData(testKey, out data)).Returns(true).AssignsOutAndRefParameters(new TestClass());
```

Comment: Works.I didn't realize that I was actually giving the compiler an Expression<TDelegate> there. I don't think its arguments are treated like method arguments.